# REST API Design two resources together

Tags: rest, metamug

How to make API as `/account/login` in the metamug console. I already have the account resource. But I want login to be accessible with it.

Since metamug doesn't allow two resources together, how can I achieve this?

It will allow `/account/123/login`, but I don't want that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per REST architectural style, `/account/123/login` is the correct implementation.
Metamug follows the style and will not allow consecutive resources in the path.

The only way to make this url work is to think of login as an identifier. So this becomes an [Item request](https://metamug.com/docs/resource-file.php#collection-&-item-request).

This being the login request, we will use POST method.

```
<Request method="POST" item="true">
     <Query when="$id eq login"> 
       select userid from user where username = $user 
       and password = $pass 
     <Query>
</Request>
```

Further reading. https://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html

Comment: What are “REST Specifications”?

Comment: The specs laid out by Roy Fielding. People who dont follow them should watch this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSKp2StlS6s

Comment: REST isn't a protocol, just an architectural style which when followed consistently helps in decoupling clients from servers by relying on an intermediary media type both parties agree on, using links to reference onto other resources and giving them meaningful names (HATEOAS) instead of forcing clients to parse URIs and interpret the semantics of it, and relying on the semantics of the underlying transport protocol to increase interoperability. Doing anything other will just path the way to an RPC like API that will break clients with certainty on changes of that API

Comment: @Sorter Can you give a reference to a spec laid out by Roy Fielding that requires `/account/123/login`?

Comment: Btw, I think the Richardson maturity model is highly overrated especially in terms of REST. First, level 3 needs to be in place and even with level 3 enabled it isn't a guarantee that the resulting architecture used follows REST principles, think of not building up on common specialized media types but customized application/json messages. A client has to have some a-priori knowledge about the data it receives and will fail if the server ever sends anything different.

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov here is his twitter handle https://twitter.com/fielding why not ask him. Btw in his bio he states he standardized the URIs. I guess that's what you are looking for.

Comment: @Sorter No, he standardized the [generic syntax of URIs](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986). His [REST dissertation](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm) has no requirements on the internal structure of URLs. Your answer’s claim about “specs” is wrong.

Comment: He also took part in the standardization of HTTP and PATCH and further stuff, but what has this to do with the actual question of @VasiliyFaronov? URIs in REST actually don't have to be pretty or human-friendly as clients should determine their intentions by the relation name and not parse any semantics from the URL tokens. A relation name might be something simple like `prev`, `next`, `self`, `first`, `last`, ... and they might be standardized by further protocols or defined in media types itself

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov I did good amount of search and agree with you. Updated my answer. I couldn't find a single RFC stating the specs. Its just an architectural style. Thanks for the healthy discussion.

Comment: _"is **the correct** implementation"_ is too strong though. I would say it's _a valid_ URI.

Comment: @Sorter Thank you for your effort, but your updated text still misses the point. The REST architectural style, as defined by Fielding, does not mandate URL structure. The whole point of Fielding’s REST is decoupling the server from the client. `/_content/api.dll?ENTITY=account&ID=123` is a perfectly good URL in Fielding’s REST, as long as the server explicitly communicates it to the client in a hyperlink.